# Jquery and trigger a click on a hidden button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a hidden button on a form that I need to click in order to fire an asyncpostback trigger that's attached to an update panel.

How is this done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('#myHiddenButton').trigger("click");
```

Or just

```
$('#myHiddenButton').click();
```

See [Events/Trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger)

Comment: That would be caused by something else, those are the ways to trigger a click event.

Comment: This will not work if you have the button's Visible property = False.  You have to use css. Visible="False" breaks jquery click().

Answer (score 13):

For the Webform: if you set the Visible property to false; typically in .net the control will not be rendered in the HTML output after the page is processed. Therefore as far as jQuery is concerned, the button does not exist.

You can do a View Source on the page to verify this.

If you want to do this, instead of using the Visible property, you can do something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="HiddenButtonID" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />
```

Then you can using jQuery to click button as :

```
$("#HiddenButtonID").click(); //Remember that in button, you must set ClientIDMode = "static"
```

or

```
$("#<%=HiddenButtonID.ClientID%>").Click();
```

Comment: The style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" did the trick. I was using visible="false"

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$("#buttonid").click();
```